# SAS put variable format in title

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a variable called `agegroup` which has many categories, eg: 1="0-5" 2="6-10" etc.

If I create a macro to print data by `agegroup` and wanted to have age group format in the title, how can I do this?

```
%macro ageprint(agegrp=1);
 proc print data=age;
 title "Age group &agegrp";
 run;
%mend;
```

if I run this macro I would like the title be printed as "Age group 0-5" instead of "age group 1".

Anyone has hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the #byval(age) option as well, it takes on the formatted value in the title:

```
proc format ;
value grpformat
        0 - 12 = '0 - 12'
        12 - 14 = '12 -  14'
        other = 'other'
            ;
run;

proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class; by age; run;

proc print data=class;
by age;
format age grpformat.;
title "Age Group #byval(age)";
run;
```

You can still use the same method if you need a macro to control where the output was going for example:

```
%macro ageprint(agegrp=1);
 proc print data=age;
 by agegrp;
 title "Age group #byval(agegrp)";
 run;
 %mend;
```

Comment: Hi Reese, Thanks for your response! I tried your solution in my macro, but '#byval' was literlly printed out. NOt sure where the issue was.

Comment: without your code hard to tell as well, you have to include the by in the proc as well.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
proc format ;
value grpformat
        0 - 5 = '0 - 5'
        6 - 10 = '6 -  10'
        other = 'other'
            ;
run;

%macro ageprint(agegrp);
 proc print data=age;
  where agegrp=&agegrp;
 title "Age group %sysfunc(putn(&agegrp, grpformat.))";
 run;
%mend;

%ageprint(agegrp=2);
%ageprint(agegrp=8);
```